# Java: Warning: Handler is a raw type. References to generic type Handler<C> should be parameterized

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, handler

I have a HandlerResolverImpl class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.HandlerResolver;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.PortInfo;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;

public class HandlerResolverImpl implements HandlerResolver {

    private List<Handler<SOAPMessageContext>> handlerList;

    public HandlerResolverImpl() {
    }

    public HandlerResolverImpl(final HeaderHandler headerHandler) {
        handlerList = new ArrayList<>();
        handlerList.add(headerHandler);
    }

    public List<Handler<SOAPMessageContext>> getHandlerList() {
        return new ArrayList<>(handlerList);
    }

    public void setHandlerList(final List<Handler<SOAPMessageContext>> handlerList) {
        this.handlerList = new ArrayList<>(handlerList);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Handler> getHandlerChain(final PortInfo portInfo) {
        return new ArrayList<>(this.handlerList);
    }

}
```

The interface HandlerResolver

```
/** 
 *  {@code HandlerResolver} is an interface implemented
 *  by an application to get control over the handler chain
 *  set on proxy/dispatch objects at the time of their creation.
 *  <p>
 *  A {@code HandlerResolver} may be set on a {@code Service}
 *  using the {@code setHandlerResolver} method.
 *  <p>
 *  When the runtime invokes a {@code HandlerResolver}, it will
 *  pass it a {@code PortInfo} object containing information
 *  about the port that the proxy/dispatch object will be accessing.
 *
 *  @see javax.xml.ws.Service#setHandlerResolver
 *
 *  @since 1.6, JAX-WS 2.0
**/
public interface HandlerResolver {

  /** 
   *  Gets the handler chain for the specified port.
   *
   *  @param portInfo Contains information about the port being accessed.
   *  @return {@code java.util.List<Handler>} chain
  **/
  public java.util.List<Handler> getHandlerChain(PortInfo portInfo);
}
```

And the generic interface Handler

```
import javax.xml.ws.ProtocolException;

/** The {@code Handler} interface
 *  is the base interface for JAX-WS handlers.
 *
 * @param <C> message context
 *  @since 1.6, JAX-WS 2.0
**/
public interface Handler<C extends MessageContext> {

  /** The {@code handleMessage} method is invoked for normal processing
   *  of inbound and outbound messages. Refer to the description of the handler
   *  framework in the JAX-WS specification for full details.
   *
   *  @param context the message context.
   *  @return An indication of whether handler processing should continue for
   *  the current message
   *                 <ul>
   *                 <li>Return {@code true} to continue
   *                     processing.</li>
   *                 <li>Return {@code false} to block
   *                     processing.</li>
   *                  </ul>
   *  @throws RuntimeException Causes the JAX-WS runtime to cease
   *    handler processing and generate a fault.
   *  @throws ProtocolException Causes the JAX-WS runtime to switch to
   *    fault message processing.
  **/
  public boolean handleMessage(C context);

  /** The {@code handleFault} method is invoked for fault message
   *  processing.  Refer to the description of the handler
   *  framework in the JAX-WS specification for full details.
   *
   *  @param context the message context
   *  @return An indication of whether handler fault processing should continue
   *  for the current message
   *                 <ul>
   *                 <li>Return {@code true} to continue
   *                     processing.</li>
   *                 <li>Return {@code false} to block
   *                     processing.</li>
   *                  </ul>
   *  @throws RuntimeException Causes the JAX-WS runtime to cease
   *    handler fault processing and dispatch the fault.
   *  @throws ProtocolException Causes the JAX-WS runtime to cease
   *    handler fault processing and dispatch the fault.
  **/
  public boolean handleFault(C context);

  /**
   * Called at the conclusion of a message exchange pattern just prior to
   * the JAX-WS runtime dispatching a message, fault or exception.  Refer to
   * the description of the handler
   * framework in the JAX-WS specification for full details.
   *
   * @param context the message context
  **/
  public void close(MessageContext context);
}
```

For the method **List getHandlerChain(final PortInfo portInfo)**

I get the warning: Handler is a raw type. References to generic type Handler should be parameterized.

Since the method defined on the HandlerResolverImpl Interface doesn't implement the Handler type as generic, is it possible to avoid this warning?

I tried several ideas, but I'm stuck trying to solve this warning correctly.

Comment: "*Since the method defined on the HandlerResolverImpl Interface doesn't implement the Handler type as generic, is it possible to avoid this warning?*" - `@SuppressWarning("rawtypes")`. But you should really fix the issue properly by parameterizing the `List<Handler<...>>`.

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") removes the warning of course but hides the original problem. So what would be a proper way of parametrizing the getHandlerChain method with the conditions imposed by the HandlerResolver Interface?

Comment: Not use that (badly designed) interface. if you have to use the interface and cannot refactor it, then this is pretty much unfixable.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. How to fix the sonar issue for above requirement ?